# Defective connection between radiator fan relay and ignition?

Tags: toyota, ignition, corolla, fan, relay

I have a Toyota AE101 DX Corolla. When I turn the key to start the car it does not tumble.

It turned out that the fan relay doesn't come on with the key turned on like it usually does. Mind you this relay was tested to be in good health. 
After jumpering the contacts of the fan relay port to turn on the fan, the car was able to tumble and start successfully.

It appears that there is a safety, that the fan has to turn on to be able to switch on the car.

How do i diagnose and repair the electrical connection between the ignition side and the fan relay ?

Comment: Are still having this problem?

Comment: No.  It was a fuse and thermostat relay.